# How to assign rowsums of a dataframe in R along a column in the same dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, rowsum

I have the following data frame in R

```
 DF1<-data.frame("S"=c("A", "B", "C"))
 namelist<-c("A", "B", "C")
 DF1[c("A", "B", "C")]<-c(1,2,3)
 DF1$B<-DF1$B*2
```

I have created a new column Sum as follows

```
  DF1$Sum<-0
```

The resulting dataframe is as follows

```
 S A B C Sum
 A 1 2 1   0
 B 2 4 2   0
 C 3 6 3   0
```

I want the values in Sum to be filled in such a way that the values against row A of Sum will be equal to the sum of the entries in column A, and similarly for B and C. The result should be as follows

```
  S A B C Sum
1 A 1 2 1   6
2 B 2 4 2   10
3 C 3 6 3   6
```

I have tried the following code

```
 for( i in 1:nrow(DF1)){
  for( j in namelist){
 DF1$Sum[DF1$S[j][i]]=sum(DF1[,j])
  }}
```

I am not getting the desired result. 
I am getting the following output. I request someone to help me here.

```
  S A B C Sum
1 A 1 2 1   0
2 B 2 4 2   0
3 C 3 6 3   0
```

Comment: yes it should. Apologies for the typo. have corrected the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick loop that accomplished your goal

```
for(i in 1:nrow(DF1)){
DF1$SUM[i] <- sum(DF1[,i+1])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
DF1 %>%
 mutate(sum = colSums(.[-1]))

  S A B C sum
1 A 1 2 1   6
2 B 2 4 2  12
3 C 3 6 3   6
```

Or the same with `base R`:

```
DF1$sum <- colSums(DF1[-1])
```

Comment: @David Arenburg a nice simplification, thank you :) Honestly, with `dplyr` it's just a fixation, here it's really not important.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general way to do it with arbitrary sequence of characters, that is if the characters are not in the same order as the columns

```
tmp=colSums(DF1[,-1])
tmp2=data.frame(S=names(tmp),Sum=tmp)
merge(DF1,tmp2,by="S")
```